# How can I modify the snap autorefresh frequency?

Tags: snap

All the snaps, by default, are updated automatically when there is a new version available. I would like this update to happen a lot more often, maybe at most 10 minutes after the new version is published.

How can I make the refresh job to be triggered more often?

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://snapcraft.io/docs/core/usage) help? It implies that you can run "snap refresh" in a script and schedule it using cron or any other similar utility.

```
> When you’re signed into the store, snaps are updated automatically in
> the background to the latest version, every day. This can also be done
> manually using snap refresh for either all installed snaps or by
> specifying a particular snap to refresh.
```

There doesn't seem to be any configuration file to affect the autorefresh frequency of snap.

Answer (score 0):

It seems changing the frequency is now possible using

```
snap set system refresh.timer=<frequency>
```

With `<frequency>` as described in the [docs](https://snapcraft.io/docs/timer-string-format).

Sources:
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-change-snap-refresh-update.html
[How can I disable automatic update for a single snap in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131182/how-can-i-disable-automatic-update-for-a-single-snap-in-ubuntu/1131184#1131184)