# How to avoid apps upgrading with snap

Tags: package-management, upgrade, snap, versions, blender

I'm trying to "pin" my current Blender version. My hardware is a bit old to run Blender 4.0 so I aimed to use the **LTS** version of it (which is now at version 3.x).

I know this is possible to do with Flatpak, I've been looking for days for a way to do this with snap packages (to avoid me a headache later). Is this even possible to do with snap? Is it even a way to **disable** upgrades for a specific snap?

I know I can revert a snap, but I would like to exclude it from upgrades (I guess at some point 4.x would become a LTS release)

Comment: Have you seen: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131182/how-can-i-disable-automatic-update-for-a-single-snap-in-ubuntu

Comment: @JohnCarter thanks, it is kind of disappointing all the workarounds but it gives me a good idea of what I can do

Comment: Workarounds are all you will get. You are trying to defeat a key feature that snapd is specifically designed for. You're asking for a swimming pool without all that pesky water.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica that's a discussion to have with the people developing snapd and snaps in general, not here.  "feature" or not, this isn't the place to field that discussion.